Computation Questions on Tensor Products
I'm currently studying tensor products with Axler "Linear Algebra Done Right". However, I cannot find any good example of computational-style questions involving tensor products --- all questions on the book seem to be proof-style. I also cannot possibly think of what computational questions involving tensor products would look like.
Do you have tips for studying the computational side of tensor products?
Thanks

I do not know that book. Does it say at least that in tensor components $\otimes$ is nothing else than the Kronecker product? This should get you started to do those, imo simple, calculations.
